# Error loading CDN in my case

Tags: html, css, wamp, cdn

hi I am trying to setup my wamp in my windows and I have couple CDN files to load. However,
when I tried to load my page. I got bunch of errors saying 403 forbidden. Can someone help me to solve this? Thanks

my index.html is in

```
wamp/www/test/index.html

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min"></script>
```

error

```
GET http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min 403 (Forbidden) 
GET http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min"> 403 (Forbidden)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `.js` at the end of your sources.  Should be:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: god..that was dumb. i didn't see it. Thanks

Comment: @FlyingCat - Hey ... we all make those mistakes now and then =D